# Avoid using temporary file for intelhex conversion

Tags: python, file, hex

I want to use Intel hex output of one files as C array in another file. Hence I created following python script.

This script works. But I am always creating a temporary file for storing intermediate intel hex to binary data. Is there any by which I can avoid this temp file.

```
import intelhex
def Create_C_Array(fin , fout ):
    intelhex.hex2bin(fin,"Temp.bin",None,None,None,None)

    f = open("Temp.bin",'rb')
    fo = open(fout,'w+')

    #write array header
    fo.write("__align(4) const unsigned char Myarray[] =  \n {")

    content = f.read()

    hex = str(binascii.hexlify(content),'ascii')

    formated_hex = '0x' + ' , 0x'.join(hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(hex),2))

    fo.write(formated_hex)

    fo.write("} ;\n\r")
```

Comment: Did you try StringIO or cStringIO module? That should be a good match as it offers file like methods on a string ...

Comment: The [API documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/IntelHex/part2-5.html) explains how to store the date in a string.